# Using Queue in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, queue

I'm trying to run the following in Eclipse (using PyDev) and I keep getting error :

**q = queue.Queue(maxsize=0)
NameError: global name 'queue' is not defined**

I've checked the documentations and appears that is how its supposed to be placed. Am I missing something here? Is it how PyDev works? or missing something in the code? Thanks for all help.

```
from queue import *

def worker():
    while True:
        item = q.get()
        do_work(item)
        q.task_done()

def main():

    q = queue.Queue(maxsize=0)
    for i in range(num_worker_threads):
         t = Thread(target=worker)
         t.daemon = True
         t.start()

    for item in source():
        q.put(item)

    q.join()       # block until all tasks are done

main()
```

Using: 
Eclipse SDK

Version: 3.8.1
Build id: M20120914-1540

and Python 3.3

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You do

```
from queue import *
```

This imports all the classes from the `queue` module already. Change that line to

```
q = Queue(maxsize=0)
```

> CAREFUL: "*Wildcard imports (from  import *) should be avoided, as they make it unclear which names are present in the namespace, confusing both readers and many automated tools".* ([Python PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#id23))

As an alternative, one could use:

```py
from queue import Queue

q = Queue(maxsize=0)
```

Comment: Thank you! Now why does it do that? I thought importing them all via the * works better or something.

Comment: It's not about working better or worse- it's that when you use the `from queue` at the top you no longer need to specify `queue.` when you call it. In some ways that is "better" (it's a shorter line of code) in some ways it is "worse" (someone reading the code doesn't know where that class came from)

Comment: It should probably be noted that this is considered bad practice for big projects - "PEP-8 recommends avoiding wildcard imports ( from some_module
import * ), and it’s absolutely right. One of the most exciting reasons
is that it opens your code up to some interesting ways to break in a
multideveloper environment." [How to Make Mistakes in Python](http://www.oreilly.com/programming/free/how-to-make-mistakes-in-python.csp)

Answer (score 7):

That's because you're using : `from queue import *`

and then you're trying to use :

```
queue.Queue(maxsize=0)
```

remove the `queue` part, because `from queue import *` imports all the attributes to the current namespace. :

```
Queue(maxsize=0)
```

or use `import queue` instead of `from queue import *`.

Answer (score 1):

If you import `from queue import *` this is mean that all classes and functions importing in you code fully. So you must not write name of the module, just `q = Queue(maxsize=100)`. But if you want use classes with name of module: `q = queue.Queue(maxsize=100)` you mast write another import string: `import queue`, this is mean that you import all module with all functions not only all functions that in first case.

Answer (score 1):

make sure your code is not under `queue.py` rename it to something else.
if your file name is queue.py it will try to search in the same file.

Comment: Thanks @Mahadev. I named my file `queue.py` and it was not working. After renaming the file, the issue was resolved.

Answer (score -5):

You Can install kombu with 
pip  install kombu

and then Import queue Just like this

from kombu import  Queue

Comment: Why would anyone do this if Queue is implemented to python by default ?