# Multiprocessing at multiple steps: How to save returned objects?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am new to multiporcessing and have some very basic queries.

I have three functions (`fun1(<list>),fun2(<dict>,<int>),fun3(<dict>,<dict>)`) that can be parallelized. The output of `fun1` (a dictionary) is the input for `fun2` and so on.

I have to consolidate the output of all the workers running `fun1` before passing it on to `fun2` (similarly for `fun2 -> fun3` transition).

Consider this code:

```
if __name__=='__main__':
    process1=[]
    for i in range(args.numcores):
        p1=Process(target=fun1, args=(m[i],))
        process1.append(p1)
        p1.start()
    for p in process1:  
        p.join()

    process2=[]
    for i in range(args.numcores):
        p2=Process(target=fun2, args=(g,j, ))
        process1.append(p1)
        p2.start()
    for p in process2:  
        p.join()
```

1. I can merge the dictionaries returned by the different workers but how do I save those return values in the first place (in other words, where are the return objects saved)?
2. since `p2.start()` follows `p1.join()`, does this mean that `process2` will start after `process1` terminates ?

Comment: [`multiprocessing.Pool`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.pool) may be useful to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(2.) Yes, your program will not continue past the join() before the process is finished.

(1.) You can use a queue or an array (which you lock with a mutex), this way you can add the return data to a (multiprocessing.)Queue or array from your functions (in the case of array or non-multiprocessing type, use a lock to ensure that they are not accessed simultaneously). Then you can read the value from the queue/array afterwards.

Comment: is lock necessary if i use queues.. pythondocs says that synchronization primitives like locks are not necessary with pipes and queues. does it mean that multiple processes putting objects in the same queue wont clash ?

Comment: No, it is not necessary to manually lock using queues. You can specify blocking and timeouts to the Queue functions as described in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Check out Python's multiprocessing.Queue class for consolidating the outputs.  The general idea is that you wrap the functions in another function that appends the result of each function to a Queue.  Then, you pull from the queue as functions terminate.

See [Using Queue in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14584958/using-queue-in-python) for a decent example (albiet with threads instead of processes)

http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue